# PHP session variables won't set when submitting form, even though same inputs work to update database

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I can set session variables manually in a php file.
I can't get session variables to set using input variables from an html form.
I'm confused because the same input variables work when I use them to update a mySQL database.

**Here is the php file that successfully sets a session variable:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    $_SESSION['username'] = "brandonpetaccio";
    
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

**I test the session variables by echoing them in a separate php file:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    
    echo $_SESSION['username']."<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['name1']."<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['name2'];
?>
```

Username was already set in the first file. I am trying to set name1 and name2 using an html form.

**Here is the file with the form. It contains php and html:**

```
<?php
// STARTS SESSION FOR THIS PAGE
session_start();

// CONNECTS TO DATABASE
include 'dragon-conn.php';


// // NAME INPUTS
$iName1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dragonden, $_REQUEST['iName1']);
$iName2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dragonden, $_REQUEST['iName2']);

// SET SESSION VARIABLES
$_SESSION['name1'] = $iName1;
$_SESSION['name2'] = $iName2;

?>

<html lang="en">

<form method = "post" class="mt-5">
                <!--NAME-->
                <h2>People</h2>
                <label for="iName1" class="" style="font-weight:bold;">First Name</label>
                <input id="iName1" name="iName1" type="text" class="spaceless form-control username m-1">
                <label for="iName2" class="mt-1" style="font-weight:bold;">Last Name</label>
                <input id="iName2" name="iName2" type="text" class="spaceless form-control username m-1">
                
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline m-2">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="customer">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="customer">
                    Customer
                  </label>
                </div>
                
                <div class="form-check form-check-inline m-2">
                  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="employee">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="employee">
                    Employee
                  </label>
                </div>
                <!--SUBMIT-->
                <input type="submit" id="addme" class="btn btn-primary m-1" value="Add Me">
                
            </form>

</html>
```

After submitting the form with input, I refresh the php file that echos the three session variables. The first session variable is still set, and echos. The last two session variables do not echo.

I have `session_start();` at the top of each file. The same input variables work when updating the database. I don't understand why they don't work when trying to set session variables via the html form.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Hm, ok... So close everything... open the form... then open the echo file?

Comment: Do you think a named session would make it work, even if the files are open at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

A commenter (whose response I no longer see) pointed out that the files are not in the same session if they are open concurrently. I closed the files; I opened the form and submitted with input; then I opened the 'echo' file, and it echoed the submitted input. SOLVED.

follow-up: would named sessions help insure that tabs are in the same session?